# Best practice for navigating to new view controller while still waiting for data

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

Right now I have a tableviewcontroller. When I click on one of the cells, I segue to a new viewcontroller that displays details about the item I clicked on.

Sometimes not all of the info I need has been loaded yet (especially on slow connections), so I'm trying to load it in the background even after the segue. I know I could just freeze the main thread and wait for my data to load, but I'd rather have a fluent interface.

For example, if a user's profile picture isn't loaded yet, then a placeholder image is shown and replaced when the real one loads in. I can't seem to get this behavior to work though. Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
func onItemTap(send:AnyObject){

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: OtherViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OtherViewController") as! OtherViewController

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        while(self.parseUser == nil){//wait for it to load}
        let profImage = (self.parseUser?.valueForKey("profilePictureLarge") as! PFFile)
        profImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) && vc.profileImageView != nil{

                vc.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                vc.userNameLabel.text = self.parseUser?.valueForKey("displayName") as? String
                vc.parseUser = self.parseUser
                vc.pfObject = self.parseObject
            }
        })
    })
    //these are sent no matter what, but are replaced by background thread if needed
    vc.parseUser = self.parseUser
    vc.pfObject = self.parseObject

    holder?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I'm not sure what I should really be doing. This seems to work in some cases, but just not at all most of the time.

How can I asynchronously send data that is being loaded somewhere on a background thread and have it reliably show up when I need it?

Comment: To avoid problems, you can block list view controller with progress hud until request is completed, or show blank details view controller with activity indicator and when request is completed show your information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)` block to `viewWillAppear()` of view controller being pushed.

Actually you don't need to use `dispatch_async` since you're already calling asynchronous `PFQuery`. So your viewcontroller's `viewWillAppear()` method will look like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){

  self.userNameLabel.text = self.parseUser?.valueForKey("displayName") as? String
  let profImage = (self.parseUser?.valueForKey("profilePictureLarge") as! PFFile)

  profImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
    if (error == nil) && self.profileImageView != nil{     
      self.profileImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    }
  })

}
```

Additionally, if you could, take a look into `PFImageView` documentation (it is inside `ParseUI.framework`). 
It makes setting images from `PFFile` much easier.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to wait until parseUser is loaded on the previous view before I can send it to this one. Otherwise it's always nil when I get here and I can't do any of this.

Comment: What exactly takes a lot of time to download user's data? Maybe you can defer download process to the moment when data is needed?

Comment: Haha, well I feel silly now. The reason it's taking so long is that I am doing too much stuff on parseUser's willset. So I am loading a couple of images before it can even be resolved. I think this is real source of my problem. Before you asked that question I never thought about it being too big :)

Comment: Great that you found solution! Please, reply, if problem persists.

Comment: It works perfectly now! I delegated all of that work to a new function and named it njuriSavedMyLife() to commemorate your help.

Comment: I'm glad that pointed you in the right direction. Finally, I can say, that I have a function named after me . Happy coding!